# Testing a slugish characteristics (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm having trouble testing a 'parameterize' characteristic. Basically what I am trying to do is something like I have below.

```
'Murtis Smith'.parameterize
'murtis-smith'
```

Only in this instance i'm using [this gem here](https://github.com/franckverrot/activevalidators) and therefore I am allowed to create this as a validation. By adding the 'slug true' it takes care of the 'parameterize' work.

```
validates :name, allow_nil: true, slug: true
```

My question is, i'm having trouble setting this up as a model spec. What I have below is my first approach. The test still fails and just returns 'murtis smith' not what I was hoping to be 'murtis-smith'.  Would anyone have any idea on how I can test this? (or is it better to avoid using this gem?)

```
it 'becomes slugish' do
  player.name = "murtis smith"
  player.save

  expect(player.name).to eq 'murtis-smith'
end
```

Comment: `player.name` isn't a slug. So, it doesn't seem to make sense to use `slug: true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The test still fails and just returns 'murtis smith' not what I was hoping to be 'murtis-smith'.

Why would you hope the name to become "murtis-smith"? It's a validator, not a converter/transformer. It works as it should.

#### [Source code](https://github.com/franckverrot/activevalidators/blob/9fc8b64d5a9ea1e64007cbcf9c78189f0b7735a2/lib/active_validators/active_model/validations/slug_validator.rb):

```
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value.nil?
      record.errors.add(attribute, :blank)
    elsif value != value.parameterize
      record.errors.add(attribute)
    end
  end
```

Also, there's a hidden failure in your spec. Try `player.save!` and you'll see.

Comment: Looks like the 'player.save!' was exactly what I was missing.  Thank you good sir!